# BooleanSupplier usage scenarios

Tags: java-8

I'm trying to understand the use case scenarios when I should consider using `BooleanSupplier`. Of most of the examples in its explanation, I get this one the most. I want to understand what advantage does using `BooleanSupplier` provide me than the simple comparison?

```
    String s1 = "ABC";
    String s2 = "ABC";

    BooleanSupplier stringEquals = () -> s1.equals(s2);
    System.out.println(stringEquals.getAsBoolean());
```

as opppsed to this-

```
    System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

Comment: Simply put... don't use it until you stumble upon a case where it's useful :) Really, you could ask the same thing about any other type (why should I use `BinaryOperator<Integer>` instead of just writing `1+1`?)

Comment: It's interesting to see what use the JDK actually makes of its own functional interfaces (i.e. those defined in **java.util.function**). To do that, just look up the relevant Javadoc specification, and then click **USE** at the top of the screen. For what it's worth, the JDK doesn't use **BooleanSupplier** in its API at all: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/class-use/BooleanSupplier.html

Comment: I just had this use case: I'm writing a library function that processes a large number of files. Between each file the client of the library should have a chance to cancel the operation. So the signature becomes `process(List<File> toProcess, BooleanSupplier shouldContinue) {...}` The `process` method then performs `if (!shouldContinue.getAsBoolean()) { return; }` between each file, and the client can invoke it using `process(allFiles, this::getShouldContinue)`. (Arguably however, I'm better off with a more specific interface, because `getAsBoolean` isn't very informative.)

Answer (score 11):

In theory, the main reason I might use `Supplier`s in general is, as @Eugene says in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353759/1876620), to defer execution. In practice, though, I've never had any reason to use `BooleanSupplier` specifically. What is more, I'm finding it really difficult to come up with a real life usage scenario...

Despite this, I think it might be worth showing a typical usage of `Supplier<String>`. I hope this could shed some light on the use of suppliers in general.

The typical example would be logging. Suppose you have to log the result of a very expensive computation that returns a value, but only when log level is set to `DEBUG`. Let's say that this very expensive computation is represented by the method `veryExpensive()`, which returns a value (the return type is not important for the sake of the example).

The traditional usage pattern is to use an `if` statement, so we only execute the very expensive computation when `DEBUG` log level is enabled:

```
if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("veryExpensive() returned: " + veryExpensive());
}
```

This works as expected, because if the log level is set to e.g. `INFO`, we'll never invoke `veryExpensive()`. But now imagine you have this same pattern repeated all over your code. Pretty nice, uh? A simple task such as logging has polluted all your code with `if` statements... (And I'm not inventing this, I've actually seen this pattern a lot of times).

Now think what would happen if `logger.debug` accepted a `Supplier<String>` instead of a plain `String` value. In this case, we wouldn't need the `if` statement any more, because the logic to extract the `String` value to log would now reside in the `logger.debug` method's implementation. The usage pattern would now be:

```
logger.debug(() -> "veryExpensive() returned: " + veryExpensive());
```

Where `() -> "veryExpensive() returned: " + veryExpensive()` is a `Supplier<String>`.

This works very well because the execution of `veryExpensive()` is deferred until the `logger.debug` method needs to actually log the `String` returned by the `Supplier<String>`, and this will only happen if the `DEBUG` log level is enabled.

Comment: reading this answer reminded me of watching some youtube video of a guy explaining exactly what you said here and also from my favourite Java-8 book (Java-8 in action) also mentioning this. completely went out of my mind when posting my answer. although I was up until 3-4 am (probably explains my lack of concentration.) +1 as usual for the nice detailed answers ;)

Comment: Hey @Aominè Thank you very much for your kind words. I haven't neither seen that video nor read that book, but I remember looking at some logging framework taking this approach, I think LOG4J 2 is designed this way

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner +1 this shoud be the accepted answer.

Comment: In case of `java.util.logging`, it has already [a method accepting a `Supplier<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#log-java.util.logging.Level-java.util.function.Supplier-), the type of whatever you format into the string being irrelevant… so you would use `logger.finest(() -> "veryExpensive() returned: "+veryExpensive());` for your example.

Comment: @Holger agreed, `Supplier<String>` makes much more sense than a `BooleanSupplier` in this scenario. I thought of overloaded methods accepting different suppliers, but they're not necessary if you are in charge of formatting the string. I think this makes my example quite convoluted... Besides, specifically to my example, we'd need to deal with the varargs argument. Hmmmm, I don't like this answer any more...

Comment: “overloaded methods accepting different suppliers” doesn’t work due to type erasure. Also, the only real advantage of using `BooleanSupplier` instead of `Supplier<Boolean>` is that the former guarantees to never return `null`. And perhaps a small plus on the semantic side, if whoever receives it is supposed to poll an encapsulated condition later-on or regularly.

Comment: @Holger I meant overloaded with specialized suppliers, but never mind, now I see how wrong my approach was. I'm at the phone now, but will delete this misleading answer as soon as I reach a PC

Comment: Don’t remove it; since the OP seems to have struggled with the concept of suppliers in general, you don’t need a perfect example specific to `BooleanSupplier`. There’s no answer with a better example anyway.

Comment: @Holger I've edited my answer based on your valuable feedback. I'd like to take the opportunity to express my gratitude not only for all your excellent answers, but also and especially for all your comments, suggestions and corrections to other posts. In my case, they've helped me a lot both to learn new issues and to further understand subjects I thought I knew in depth, until you questioned some of my (not very solid) arguments. I wonder if you have a compilation of your best answers, or maybe if you've thought of creating a webinar, course or even a book. I'd gladly pay for that material.

Comment: hey, when did you come in? very detailed answer, +1. one mentioned, it is trivial to use inline receiver extension function in kotlin. and it doesn't create lambda instance at all. have you started kotlin my friend?

Answer (score 3):

That is simply a specialization of a `Supplier`, as such you should really question why you need a `Supplier` *at all* and your very simple example don't show the need for one. This is needed for at least two reasons in my opinion:

First, is to defer the execution. Think `Optional.orElseGet(Supplier...)` vs `Optional.get()`. You might think that they are the same, but the first one *is only executed* if needed. Now think of the case when the returned Object is expensive to compute (like a series of DB calls for example), which one would you choose? Arguably it should be `orElseGet` via the supplied `Supplier`.

The second one is to produce an object all the time via the call to `supply`, I mean this is the name `Supplier` comes from, *to supply* values. Inside `Stream API` these are used when you would need to return a new Object, for example when merging elements in *parallel*, each Thread would get it's own holder of Objects. For an example, look at :

```
public static<T, R> Collector<T, R, R> of(
       Supplier<R> supplier,
       BiConsumer<R, T> accumulator,
       BinaryOperator<R> combiner...
```

See how the custom `Collector.of` would take the first argument as a `Supplier`, same thing would happen in `Collectors.toList` (look under the implementation) or `Collectors.toMap`, etc.

One example we use it in production is to return to the caller a `Supplier<Something>` instead of `Something`. When the caller calls `get` I am free to do whatever I want to return `Something` - we usually cache Objects for example.

Answer (score 3):

The basic idea of use functional interface (`BooleanSupplier` in here) rather than use hard code is [information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding). let's say the rest of code is invisible from you except `stringEquals.getAsBoolean()`, so we can't know the implementation of `stringEquals` any more.

The benefits of use functional interface is [decoupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) the supplier from the client code, e.g: in order to get the final result of the `stringEquals` in your example code, the client code need to know `s1` & `s2`, but the supplier or the consumer of the functional interface side without to know it. because of the implementation is encapsulated at the client side. this let the supplier side to complete its internal task without to know how the clients implements it. for more details, you can see [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

On the other hand, it is meanless that define a functional interface instance and call it immediately in the same code block.

Let's see another concrete example of `Objects#requireNotNull` as following code:

```
public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj, Supplier<String> messageSupplier) {
    if (obj == null)
        throw new NullPointerException(messageSupplier.get());
    //                                                 ^
    // the `requireNotNull` method doesn't know how to create a diagnostic message
    return obj;
}
```

We can benefits from the indirect components (functional interface in here).

- substitute with a new indirect component on demand without to change the code of the supplier side.
- make the computation lazily through the indirect component. e.g: the body of lambda of `stringEquals` doesn't to be executed until it is called in your example.
- make the final result cachable
- recording/logging the invocation of the indirect component, and so on...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example focused on the BooleanSupplier.

I have a method:

```
static WeakHashMap<K, Reference<T>> cachemap = new WeakHashMap<>();
static T getCached(K key, BooleanSupplier isOK)
{
    synchronized(cachemap)
    {
        T item = cachemap.computeIfAbsent(key, k-> new SoftReference<>(new T(k, isOK.getAsBoolean()))).get();
        if (item == null) // Could be if reference has been GC'ed
        {
            item = new T(key, isOK.getAsBoolean());
            cachemap.put(key, new SoftReference<>(item));
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

The reason I use BooleanSupplier is because often times, determination of "isOK" is a complex boolean statement including a complex Regex match.  This function basically retrieves the cached value if previously created and it has not been garbage collected and only executes the "expensive" BooleanSupplier function if the item needs to be created. My code actually uses a RedundantLock but this is easier to read.  This is also a good example of using WeakHashMap as a cache where T makes use of the key.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case there is no point in doing:

```
BooleanSupplier stringEquals = () -> s1.equals(s2);
System.out.println(stringEquals.getAsBoolean());
```

instead of just:

```
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2));
```

Therefore *no benefits*, in fact, the latter approach is arguably easier to read and has less code.

A `BooleanSupplier` aswell as any other functional interface is simply a criterion to say *"the structure of the function to be referenced must have x number of arguments and may or may not return a value"*

That said, a `BooleanSupplier` is simply a boolean-producing primitive specialization of `Supplier` thus, its job is ultimately to supply a value back to the caller (like a `getter` method).

Because `BooleanSupplier` is a functional interface you can pass it as a behaviour parameterisation to another method, make it as a return type to a method which you can then use elsewhere; as well as using it as a target type to a method that takes no args possibly doing some logic and returning a result.

When used wisely and where appropriate this can bring good benefits.

Comment: some actual examples would make your post far better... I tried to provide some, may be you an think of others https://stackoverflow.com/a/48353759/1059372

Comment: @Eugene yup, agreed that it can be better by providing further examples, although after reading your answer I am running out of ideas to provide some that you haven't already mentioned :( . sometimes you don't think of a scenario to use a Supplier until you struggle upon a problem where you say "ah i can use a Supplier here" where appropriate that is....